# Array of Dictionaries - Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to make a constructor for a custom type in Julia:

```
type Cell
  Base::Dict{String, String}
  zLayers::Array{Dict{String, String},2}
  X::Int
  Y::Int

  Cell() = new(Dict{String,String}(),[Dict{String, String}(),Dict{String, String}()],0,0)
end

try
  gamestate = Cell()
catch err
  print("connection ended with error $err\n")
end
```

Throws error:

```
connection ended with error MethodError(convert,(Array{Dict{String,String},2},[Dict{String,String}(),Dict{String,String}()]))
```

So how do we do proper initialization for Arrays of Dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was double posted and answered on the mailiglist.

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/julia-users/zE8Ri8rbfHQ

> I think you’re confusing the 2 in an Array parameter set with the number of items, when it’s the number of dimensions. I’m pretty sure you’re creating a Vector, not a Matrix.

Comment: Yes, I was not getting much response here so I posted there. I will only post on google groups until the community grows.

Comment: For some reason the julia community is much more active on the mailinglist than on StackOverflow. It's quite rear to find new questions on StackOverflow, so it's kind of boring to look for them. It's probably also a good thing, because Julia is under heavy development, and the date of the answer is often important.